# с++ класы (когда лучше только хидер, а когда лучше хидер и cpp)

Tags: c++, классы, header

При создании с++ класса обычной практикой, насколько я знаю, является создание заголовочного файла и cpp файла, но также есть возможность создать класс только в хидере.

Опишите преимущества и недостатки того и другого.

Comment: Только .h используется, если там шаблоны например.

Comment: @Andreyua прямо похоже на билет с вопроса

Comment: @KoVadim не угадал

Comment: Это вопрос про выбор компоновки конкретного класса или про организацию всего кода?

Answer (score 4):

Тут нужно делать таблицы 2 на 2

**только header**

***плюсы***

- получается header-only библиотека, очень удобно распространять.
- все функции класса автоматом инлайн. Хотя это может быть и минусом
- в boost даже выделяют отдельно [подобные библиотеки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604090/which-boost-libraries-are-header-only).

***минусы***

- легко напороться на нарушение ODR (достаточно немного макросами поиграть)
- лишняя работа линковщику (в файле не может быть двух функций с одним и тем же именем. Линковщику нужно аккуратно все найти).
- все детали реализации наружу
- сложно инициализировать статические переменные

**header + cpp**

***плюсы***

- легко использовать [pimpl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) и скрыть детали.
- легко подменять cpp файл и менять реализации.
- обычно быстрее компилируется

***минусы***

- шаблоны в cpp очень сложно вынести.
- лишний файл, который нужно не забыть добавить в список компиляции, иначе будут интересные ошибки линковки
- сложно распространять скомпилированные файлы.

Comment: вот интересно, кто проминусовал, хоть бы прокоментировали

Comment: Я плюсанул, а как вы видите, что минусовали?

Comment: а нужно нажать не на треугольники, а на само число.

Answer (score 2):

Если это мелкий класс, все функции которого - одна-две строки, не тянущий за собой включение десятка заголовочных файлов - то его вполне можно разместить в заголовочном файле. Плюс при этом в том, что все его функции могут быть встроены в код, а значит - более быстрая программа. Минус - его придется компилировать везде, где включается этот файл, а также подтягивать все файлы, от которых зависит реализация класса. Изменение в какой-то букве класса ведет к перекомпиляции всех файлов, куда включен данный заголовочный файл.

В отдельном же файле реализация компилируется отдельно, и хранится в отдельном объектном файле, и компонуется при необходимости. В результате при изменении в каком-то месте достаточно перекомпилировать один файл, а не все. Плюс не нужно тянуть необходимые для реализации, но не для объявления заголовочные файлы.

Вполне возможна комбинация - часть простых функций типа геттеров-сеттеров :) можно реализовать прямо в заголовке; те, что помассивнее - в отдельном файле.

Примерно так...

Comment: А комбинировать можно, первое со вторым?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Часть простых функций типа геттеров-сеттеров :) можно реализовать прямо в заголовке; что помассивнее - в отдельном файле.

Answer (score 1):

Все пользовательские типы (и шаблоны и не шаблоны) рекомендуется описывать в хедерах, чтобы в любом месте программы было доступно описание класса для его использования.

Если описать тип в cpp-файле, то описание типа будет доступно только в этом cpp-файле, и экземпляры этого типа можно будет создавать только в этом cpp-файле.

UPD1:

> экземпляры этого типа можно будет создавать только в этом cpp-файле -
>   не совсем правда. В файле может быть ещё одна функция, которая будет
>   возвращать указатель на класс-предок, но создавать нужный экземпляр.

Чтобы использовать такую систему, прототип класса-предка все равно должен быть в хедере, и прототип функции создающий класс-потомок тоже должен быть в хедере, ну и зачем тогда все это? Я сам видал человека (правда давно это было и у него это было начало освоения языка Си), который cpp-файлы инклюдами в другие cpp-файлы включал. То есть у него даже все работало, но зачем забивать гвозди микроскопом? Есть механизм, созданный для определенных целей и надо просто этот механизм грамотно применять.

Comment: **экземпляры этого типа можно будет создавать только в этом cpp-файле** - не совсем правда. В файле может быть ещё одна функция, которая будет возвращать указатель на класс-предок, но создавать нужный экземпляр.